# How to get pdf buffer from response body with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I need to download a pdf while it navigates to "chrome pdf view" with puppeteer.
[this](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf) is the test link I have been using to test this.

I am trying to get the pdf buffer from the response body

```
page.on('response', async response => {
  console.log('in response');
  if (response.url().includes('.pdf')) {
    console.log(await response.text())
  }

})
await page.goto('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf')
```

but only gives me the preview data of the pdf

> <!doctype html><embed name='1FE75881C67175A5ACEE8BB8FF5B3136' style='po
> sition:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'width='100%' height='100%' src='about:blank' type='application/pdf' internalid='1FE75881C67175A5ACEE8BB8FF5B3136'>

I also tried response.buffer() but this also gives me the preview data. But I need the buffer for the actual pdf file data.

When I hit the pdf link in postman I do see the pdf data in body so I can't figure out why I can't get that in puppeteer response.

[image: here is postman response]

Comment: Do you have to use Puppeteer? Can't you download the pdf as a buffer from url?

Comment: yes because the website I'm gonna download from takes me to a URL that looks like {{ur}}/CompletedTripsPDF.aspx. I can't go to this page without clicking a button on the website

Comment: plus the request for the pdf must be authorized